# Pyspark S3 error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/MultiObjectDeleteException

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Been unsuccessful setting a spark cluster that can read AWS s3 files.   The software I used are as follows:

1. hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
2. aws-java-sdk-1.11.887.jar
3. spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz

Using python version:  Python 3.8.6

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import sys

spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .appName("AuthorsAges")
         .appName('SparkCassandraApp')
         .getOrCreate())


spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "access-key")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "secret-key")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "")


input_file='s3a://spark-test-data/Fire_Department_Calls_for_Service.csv'

file_schema = StructType([StructField("Call_Number",StringType(),True),
        StructField("Unit_ID",StringType(),True),
        StructField("Incident_Number",StringType(),True),
...
...
# Read file into a Spark DataFrame
input_df = (spark.read.format("csv") \
            .option("header", "true") \
            .schema(file_schema) \
            .load(input_file))
```

The code fails when it starts to execute the spark.read.format. It appears that it can't find the class. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 178, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o51.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/MultiObjectDeleteException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.MultiObjectDeleteException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

I've been trying to find the right combination for the above jars and python but I couldn't find the right mix. I'm getting all kinds of NoClassDefFoundError so I decided to use the latest versions of all the jars and python I listed above but still unsuccessful.

I would like to know what versions of jars and python did you use to have successfully setup a cluster that is able to access s3 using s3a via pyspark?    Thank you in advance for response/help.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue on Spark 3.0/ Hadoop 3.2. I documented my answer here as well - [AWS EKS Spark 3.0, Hadoop 3.2 Error - NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/MultiObjectDeleteException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625111/aws-eks-spark-3-0-hadoop-3-2-error-noclassdeffounderror-com-amazonaws-servic/64625374#64625374)

Use following AWS Java SDK bundle and this issue will be solved -

aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.874.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.874)

Comment: currently running into the same issue, except spark version is `3.5.0`, hadoop-aws version `3.3.4`. But, how are folks finding out whats the version for aws-java-sdk to go with the above versions? I tried looking here(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.803) since thats the one im using, but still need to toss a coin and decide whether i should use the `.874` vs. the most recent one for aws-java-sdk. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop 3.2 was built against 1.11.563; stick the full shaded sdk  of that specific version in your classpath "aws-java-sdk-bundle" and all should be well.

The SDK has been "fussy" in the past...and upgrade invariably causes surprises. For the curious [Qualifying an AWS SDK update](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/testing.html#Qualifying_an_AWS_SDK_Update%22). It's probably about time someone does it again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers, I will add my 2 cents on top of them.
Although adding the `aws-java-sdk-bundle` works perfectly, I found it better to add the specific dependencies to make the package smaller.

I replaced `aws-java-sdk-bundle` by `aws-java-sdk-sts`, `aws-java-sdk-s3`, and `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb`. The final size went from ~200MB to ~125MB.

Answer (score 0):

So I cleaned-up everything and re-installed the following versions of jars and it worked: hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar, aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.2.jar. Spark install version: spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7. Python version: Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved my problem, when I wanted to include the jar files locally so they don't have to be downloaded each time.
Using Spark 3.1.3

```
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "tests/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar")
.config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "tests/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar")
.config("spark.jars", "tests/hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar")
```